# Fastest way to determine the solution of $x^{x^x}=10^{10^n}$ with a table calculator?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponentiation

If $\lg(x)$ denotes the logarithm to base $10$, the equation $$x^{x^x}=10^{10^n}$$ is equivalent to $$x\lg(x)+\lg(\lg(x))=n$$ for $n>1$

The solution can be found by various numerical methods (newton-method, bisection method , iteration), but I wonder whether there is a method so simple that it can be applied fast with a table calcaulator giving a reasonable accurate result.

> Is there a sequence easy to calculate only with a table calculator converging "fast" to the desired solution ?

The method should especially work well for large numbers $n$. The best I found so far is the iteration $$x_{m+1}=\frac{n-\lg(\lg(x_m))}{\lg(x_m)}$$ with start value $$x_0=\frac{n}{\lg(n)-\lg(\lg(n))}$$ I am not sure for which $n$ this iteration converges. Can anyone help to find that out ?

Comment: It looks like you are using $n$ to mean two different things here.

Comment: What do you mean by a "table calculator"?

Comment: A not-programmable calculator , but with powerful enough commands, including the $\lg$-command.

Comment: I have seen $\lg x$ for the base $2$ log.  This is the first time I have seen it for base $10$.  For base $10$ I have only seen $\log x$ or $\log_{10} x$

Comment: You have written $x \lg(x)$ where I think you meant to write just $\lg(x).$

Answer (score 1):

Fixed point iteration converges when the absolute value of the derivative of the right side is less than $1$.  Since $\lg(\lg x)$ changes so slowly compared with $\lg x$ this is satisfies, so your iteration will converge if you start close enough.  Newton-Raphson will converge in fewer iterations, but it is more work to figure out the iteration in the first place, so I like your approach.